# Haskell's `group` Function

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

I implemented the `group` function:

```
group' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group' [] = []
group' xs = takeWhile (== head' xs) (sorted xs) : 
                           (group' $ dropWhile (== head' xs) (sorted xs))
                    where sorted ys   = mergesort' (ys)
                          head' (x:_) = x
```

Note - please assume `mergesort` is implemented properly.

Its signature is: `[a] -> [a]` where the latter list is sorted.

How's it look? Is `head'`'s pattern matching exhaustive? It seems to me it is since `group xs` will only be reached if `group`'s argument is non-empty, i.e. it'll always have a `head`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have made some uncommon stylistic choices which are not to your benefit, and a few things aren't doing what I think you think they're doing.

First, the stylistic elements. Your whitespace is excessive, there's no need to push everything that far to the right and out of line with the beginning of the RHS. I also would move the colon down to begin the next line, this is mostly a matter of personal style. The parentheses around `ys` are unnecessary and while harmless noise for the compiler will distract your human reader. My version would look like this.

```
group' xs = takeWhile (== head' xs) (sorted xs)
          : group' (dropWhile (== head' xs) (sorted xs))
    where sorted ys   = mergesort' ys
          head' (x:_) = x
```

Now to the meat of it. As it is, your definition of `sorted` is just giving a different name to `mergesort'`. The two uses in the main body of the function will cause `sorted xs` to be recomputed each time (ie twice!). The correct definition is not to create an inner function which is passed a list to be sorted as a parameter, but to bind a sorted version of the outer function's parameter.

```
group' xs = takeWhile (== x) sorted : group' (dropWhile (== x) sorted)
    where sorted = mergesort' xs -- Computed once, the result is used twice
          x = head sorted
```

You'll notice that I gave the same treatment to `head'`, this is less of a performance hit and more a matter of consistency. If you wanted to be really pedantic you could bind the section as well, but (and this is an art not a science) I feel that this version is less readable.

```
group' xs = takeWhile p sorted : ...
    where ...
          p = (== head sorted)
```

This is still doing more work than it needs though! Once you've made the first recursive call, the tail passed to `group'` will always already be sorted, and doesn't need to be resorted with each recursive step. One way to handle this would be to pull the main functionality of `group'` into an inner function named something like `group''` and change the body of `group'` to just be `group'' (mergesort' xs)`. Now the list is only sorted once.

I think it makes more sense though to separate the two functions entirely. There is in fact no requirement that the list being grouped is sorted, so let's relax that constraint.

```
group' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group' []     = []
group' (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (== x) xs) : group' (dropWhile (== x) xs)

elementSets :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [[a]] -- Same functionality as original group'
elementSets = group' . mergeSort'
```

And just so you see what's happening,

```
> group' [2,2,1,2,2,2]
[[2,2],[1],[2,2,2]]
> elementSets [2,2,1,2,2,2]
[[1],[2,2,2,2,2]]
```

Note that we can now find the head of the list through pattern matching instead of calling `head` because we don't need to assume the list may be out of order. We do however have to remember to add that element back to the prefix of what we're returning!

There's one more improvement we can make though! As it is, our `group'` function will walk the prefix of the list equal to the first element twice each recursive step (once for `takeWhile`, and once for `dropWhile`). We can eliminate that inefficiency by using `span` which returns the prefix matching the predicate and the remainder in one go.

```
group' (x:xs) = (x : prefix) : group' remainder
    where (prefix, remainder) = span (== x) xs
```

And there we have it.

Regarding your question about whether `head'`'s pattern matching was exhaustive, the answer is that it is not exhaustive because the definition of `head'` contained no case which would match every possible pattern (ie `head' []`). It was however "safe" to use because of how `group'` was defined, and the case of the empty list was handled through pattern matching at the outer level. In general you shouldn't rely on tricky business like that, it can be difficult to notice when coming back to code you or someone else has written, and can blow up on you if you have to change the definition of the function.

Comment: Thanks! Besides your excellent, detailed post, I especially learned from your last sentence - ` In general you shouldn't rely on tricky business like that`